# Google Charts Variable Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, api, google-visualization

Trying to make a Google Charts dashboard, but I'm having some troubles with some simple code which is driving me mad. I think it has something to do with variable scope.

Here is the code I am using to make a simple chart from a Google tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        var options = {
      width: 400,
      height: 240,
      vAxis: {minValue:0, maxValue:1000},
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      }
    };

       var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
           document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'x');
        data.addColumn('number', 'A');
        data.addColumn('number', 'B');
        data.addRow(['A', 123, 40]);
        data.addRow(['B', 17, 20]);
        var addButton = document.getElementById('unique');
        function drawChart() {
          // Disabling the buttons while the chart is drawing.
          addButton.disabled = true;
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
              function() {
                // Enabling only relevant buttons.
                addButton.disabled = (data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) >= chars.length;
              });
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        function shuffleAndDrawChart() {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); ++i) {
            for (var j = 1; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); ++j) {
              var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
              data.setValue(i, j, num);
            }
          }
          drawChart();
        }
        addButton.onclick = function() {
          data.addColumn('number', chars[data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1]);
          shuffleAndDrawChart();
        }
        drawChart();     
    </script>

    <title>Light Blue - Admin Template</title>
    <link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <?php
        require_once 'includes/ga/src/Google_Client.php';
        require_once 'includes/ga/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
        require_once 'includes/ga/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
        require_once 'includes/gaConnect.php';
        require_once 'includes/functions.php';

        if (!$client->getAccessToken()) 
            {
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            exit("<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>");
            }
        else 
            {
            $analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

            $lastmonth = date('Y') . "-" . (date('m')-1) . "-" . date('d');
            $yesterday = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . (date('d')-1);

            $visitsOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visits', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalVisits = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visits', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);

            $uniqueOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visitors', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalUnique = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visitors', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);

            $pageviewsOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:pageviews', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalPageviews = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:pageviews', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);

            $bounceRateOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visitBounceRate', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalBounceRate = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:visitBounceRate', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);

            $newVisitsOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:percentNewVisits', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalNewVisits = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:percentNewVisits', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);

            $avgTimeOverTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:avgTimeOnSite', $lastmonth, $yesterday, 'ga:date');
            $totalAvgTime = runQuery($analytics, 'ga:avgTimeOnSite', $lastmonth, $yesterday, NULL);
            }
    ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

The problem is that this code (which was copy/pasted directly from Google Dev site) does not work!!And I have no idea why!!!!
The only time this code has worked for me is if I put all of the variable declarations WITHIN the drawChart() function. Otherwise, I end up with a blank canvas and no chart.

This is so extremely frustrating and I have been trying to figure this shit out since Thursday. It is slowly killing me from the inside out and I think I might do something drastic if I don't figure it out soon.

Please help! I'm slipping into a deeper and deeper state of depression and alcoholism for every day I don't figure this issue out.

-- Edit --

I was told to check the console for any JavaScript or HTML errors. I ran FireBug JavaScript console and found no errors. If there is a better way of doing this, let me know.I am still pretty new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are missing the google loader, so the visualization API never loads.  Second, the way that code is set up, you will run into problems trying to create visualization elements before the API is loaded.  You need to wrap all of your chart code inside another function and use that function as the callback from the google loader.  It would look something like this:

```
function initialize () {
    var options = {
        width: 400,
        height: 240,
        vAxis: {minValue:0, maxValue:1000},
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'B');
    data.addRow(['A', 123, 40]);
    data.addRow(['B', 17, 20]);
    var addButton = document.getElementById('unique');
    function drawChart() {
        // Disabling the buttons while the chart is drawing.
        addButton.disabled = true;
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            // Enabling only relevant buttons.
            addButton.disabled = (data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) >= chars.length;
        });
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    function shuffleAndDrawChart() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); ++i) {
            for (var j = 1; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); ++j) {
                var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
                data.setValue(i, j, num);
            }
        }
        drawChart();
    }
    addButton.onclick = function() {
        data.addColumn('number', chars[data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1]);
        shuffleAndDrawChart();
    }
    drawChart();
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: initialize});
```

Comment: Nice!! This makes so much sense I can't believe I couldn't think of it. Thank you so so so much!